# Disable 2 finger scrolling in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I'd like to disable two-finger scrolling in my `UIScrollView`.
I subclassed it and tweaked its built-in gesture recognizers with the following code:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *mgestureRecognizer in scroller.gestureRecognizers) {     
    if ([mgestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *mpanGR = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) mgestureRecognizer;
        mpanGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1; 
        mpanGR.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;

    }

    if ([mgestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *mswipeGR = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) mgestureRecognizer;
        mswipeGR.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    }
```

For some reason, `maximumNumberOfTouches` does not seem to work. I can still scroll with one or two fingers. If I change both properties to `2`, I can successfully disable one-finger scrolling and require two touches.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21):

I realize this is an old thread, but it took me a long time to figure this out, so I thought I would share.  Here's what I did to disable two-finger scrolling:

```
// set up a two-finger pan recognizer as a dummy to steal two-finger scrolls from the scroll view
// we initialize without a target or action because we don't want the two-finger pan to be handled
UIPanGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
twoFingerPan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
twoFingerPan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerPan];
```

Comment: shouldn't it be *1* for the minimum and the maximum ? (instead of 2 ?)

Comment: The code disables 2-finger panning by eating the 2-finger pan gestures.  So min and max touches should be 2.

Comment: Worked for me and couldn't find any other way of doing it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Made our app behave much better.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using iOS SDK over 5.0, maybe you can use ui pan gesture recognizer directly.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

......

[self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this is still an issue in iOS 8, but only when the UIPanGestureRecognizer is underlying a UIScrollView. Creating a UIView with a fresh UIPanGestureRecognizer and setting its maximumNumberOfTouches property works as expected.

Submitted rdar://20890684 and copied to http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6191825677189120. Please feel free to dupe.

Answer (score 0):

***PROBLEM***:

When the *`UIPanGestureRecognizer`* is underlying a *`UIScrollView`* (which unfortunately does also effect `UIPageViewController`) the ***`maximumNumberOfTouches`*** is not behaving as expected - the ***`minimumNumberOfTouches`*** however always limits the lower end correctly.

When monitoring these parameters they seem to do their job - it's just that `UIScrollView` doesn't honor them and ignores their values!

---

***REMEDY***:

You can find the solution in my answer to:

[UIScrollView scrolling only with one finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031359/uiscrollview-scrolling-only-with-one-finger/40071412#40071412)